# How to get Current View or Application Context of Current Activity in a class of SystemUI

Tags: android

I have a big problem. In `systemUI/PhoneStatusBar` class, I want to add a childView to parrent of current `View` of running `Activity`. How to done it in `PhoneStatusBar.java` in `systemUI`.
I tried to using some method, example

```
View.getRootView()
```

or so on, but cannot get expected result. 
Hope to get success from everyone. Thanks very much

Thanks for help from you. But i would like to emphasized that "I want to get current view of running activity". I it must be done in android/frameworks/base/packages//Systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java.
I very very hope to continue receiving helps from everyone

Comment: could you post your code ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

View.getContext();

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

To add a view, you need to cast it as a ViewGroup:

```
ViewGroup addViewHere = (ViewGroup)myView;
```

Or you may need to get the parent if the problem is that you cannot add the view to the correct place in the view hierarchy:

```
ViewGroup addViewHere = (ViewGroup)myView.getParent();
```

Then assuming all layout params are correct, add it:

```
addViewHere.addView(newView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```

It should give you the root view of the activity including status bar on top